# ¿Como insertar multiples arrays usando PDO de un formulario PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, array, pdo

Hola tengo un codigo que funciona para insertar multiples registros pero estos solo de un array, planeo agregar mas inouts con diferentes arrays pero no encuentro como modificar la parte de los arreglos me imagino que en el caso del sql seria algo asi:

```
$insertStmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO productos (producto, id, etc) VALUES (:field, :id, etc)");
```

Corríjanme si estoy mal

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-add']))
    {
        $fields= (is_array($_POST['fields'])) ? $_POST['fields'] : array();
        $insertStmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO productos (producto) VALUES (:field)");

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $insertStmt->execute(array('field' => $field));
        }

                                        header("Location: productos.php");

    }
    ?>
```

Asi tengo mi input:

```
 $(container).append('<input type=text required="required" name ="fields[]" class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
    'placeholder="Producto ' + iCnt + '" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero del todo no haría un execute por cada `$field` que hay en `$fields`.

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
// el insert permite añadir una lista de valores 
// INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
$query = "insert into productos (col1, col2, col3) values "

for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($fields); $i++){
   $query .= "?, "
}

// para borrar útlima comma haces un 

$query = rtrim($query, ',');

$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 

// el numero de interogante = sizeOf($fields)
// los interogantes puedes hacer dinamicos con un bucle foreach

// count empieza desde 1
$count = 1;
foreach ($fields as $field) {
  $db->bindParam($count, $field);
  $count++;
}

// finalement ejecutas 
$db->execute()
```